# Getting an error and can't find documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to node.js and I'm following a tutorial but the code returns an error when I refresh localhost:3000/books

The error:
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Code:
app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { connectToDb, getDb } = require('./db');

console.log('starting');
// init app & middleware
const app = express();
console.log('init complete');

// db connection
let db;
connectToDb((err) => {
    console.log('connecting to db');
    if (!err) {
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('app listening on port 3000');
        });
        db = getDb();
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});


//routes
app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
    let books = [];

    db.collection('books')
        .find() // cursor toArray forEach
        .sort( { author: 1 })
        .forEach(book => books.push(book))
        .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json(books);
        })
        .catch(() => { 
             res.status(500).json({error: 'could not fetch the documents'});
        })

    res.json({mssg: "welcome to the api"});
});
```

And db.js:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
    connectToDb: (cb) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/bookstore')
        .then((client) => {
            dbConnection = client.db();
            return cb();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err);
        });
    },
    getDb: () => dbConnection
};
```

I'm hosting the mongodb server with compass:
I have a database with the name of bookstore and a collection with the name books
In books I have:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636faa18a918cf889958ea12"
  },
  "title": "Name of wind",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Patrick",
    "lastName": "Rothfuss"
  },
  "pages": 500,
  "genres": [
    "fantassy",
    "magical"
  ],
  "rating": 9,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "Ludwig",
      "body": "AWESOME!"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636facd8a918cf889958ea16"
  },
  "title": "Book of fire?",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Willem",
    "lastName": "Johnson"
  },
  "pages": 350,
  "genres": [
    "fantassy",
    "comedy"
  ],
  "rating": 6,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "Ludwig",
      "body": "BAD!"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636facd8a918cf889958ea17"
  },
  "title": "Thrones of destiny",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Jonas",
    "lastName": "Adams"
  },
  "pages": 689,
  "genres": [
    "magical",
    "fantassy"
  ],
  "rating": 10,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "Ludwig",
      "body": "The best!"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636facd8a918cf889958ea18"
  },
  "title": "Idiots!",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Jack",
    "lastName": "Phiers"
  },
  "pages": 486,
  "genres": [
    "action",
    "comedy"
  ],
  "rating": 8,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "Ludwig",
      "body": "Great!"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "636facd8a918cf889958ea19"
  },
  "title": "Where are we?",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Jone",
    "lastName": "Johnson"
  },
  "pages": 685,
  "genres": [
    "magical",
    "sci-fi"
  ],
  "rating": 7.6,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "name": "Ludwig",
      "body": "Good!"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63737fae2ea0cb2ca699eec7"
  },
  "title": "Colour Magic",
  "author": {
    "firstName": "Terry",
    "lastName": "Pretchett"
  },
  "pages": 768,
  "rating": 7,
  "genres": [
    "fantassy",
    "comedy"
  ]
}]
```

when logging out the books array I made in app.js its an empty array

Comment: delete this line `res.json({mssg: "welcome to the api"});`

Comment: Why does  that fix it? I mean it works but why?

Comment: You already used res.json() before this line, meaning you have sent the client what it needs and the client can close the connection. You cannot double-send the client data like this, so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not database.

As the error says `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, the response is being sent to the client two times.

Two times because, in the app.get() callback, you have these 2 functions running,

`res.json({mssg: "welcome to the api"});` and `db.collection('books').find()`

Both of these are async functions, and hence run parallely.
When node encounters `db.collection().find()` it starts to process it asynchronously and moves to the next line, that is `res.json()` method.

By the time `db.collection().find()` gets completed (since it is a database call, it takes time to execute), the `res.json()` would have already finished its execution, and has already sent the response. Now when `db.collection().find()` completes, inside the `.then()` block, you are sending yet another response to a client which has already received the response `{mssg: "welcome to the api"}`

Hence the error `"Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"`